# I tried the new UI button but when I try to link it I can't find the script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I put the script in MainCamera.
When I try to link it to the button, it doesn't find it.
My code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    void QuitGame () {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
 }
```

Screens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1HdZ.jpg

Thanks, Tudor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should get a reference to your quit game method because it is on **main camera** we can say `Camera.mainCamera` and do it like this `Camera.mainCamera.GetComponent<MainMenu>().QuitGame();` after getting the rerence we add an **onclick event** to our button

```
gameObject.Getcomponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Camera.mainCamera.GetComponent<MainMenu>().QuitGame();});
```